# Split ArrayList into Multiple ArrayLists depending on user input

Tags: java, arraylist

I have this program:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Enter number of nodes");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {
        nodes.add(i);
    }

    System.out.println(nodes);
    System.out.println("How many subnetworks you want? Enter Small(10), Med(30), Large(50)");
    small = sc.nextInt();
    med = sc.nextInt();
    large = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Small = " + small + "med" + med + "large" + large);
```

Now depending on value of small, medium and large and considering multiples of each of these integers, I want to split ArrayList into different arraylists or array.
For example, small = 100, med = 50, large = 10 should split main arraylist into 100 small arraylists each of size 10, 50 med arraylists each of size 30 and 10 large arraylists each of size 50.
 After the split, I want to assign some properties to elements in sublsits. And I am not sure whether it should be arraylist or array or anything else.

Comment: Are the sizes of the 100 small arraylists, 50 med,... fixed to 10, 30,...? Or are they determined based on the input of small, med and large?

Comment: For now I have kept it fixed. If I get this thing working, I will try to do them dynamic like over a range or something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use split list function.

```
private static List<List<Integer>> splitAndReturn(List<Integer> numbers,
        int size) {
    List<List<Integer>> smallList = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    int i = 0;
    while (i + size < numbers.size()) {
        smallList.add(numbers.subList(i, i + size));
        i = i + size;
    }
    smallList.add(numbers.subList(i, numbers.size()));
    return smallList;
}
```

The function will return an arrayList of arrays with each raw of size `size`. 
So if you need 100 array with size 10, then

```
splitAndReturn(yourList, 10).subList(0, 100);
```

will get you the list of arrays.

Comment: May I know what actually is count variable doing? And also for list of med size.. where each list is of size 30 and I want 40 such lists then will it be like splitAndReturn(nodes,30).subList(0,40) ?

Comment: I am getting IndexOutofBoundsException at line List<Integer> small = numbers.subList(i, numbers.size()+size);

Comment: That was a mistake, thanks for making me know. And what error

Comment: That was `i+size` sorry i have made the edit. Please check again

Comment: I am giving value for small as 50. Like I need 50 nodes in one List and 10 lists like that. So I should call it like splitAndReturn(nodes, 10).subList(0,50) right? It is giving me following errors                                                                                                                                                                                       Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: toIndex = 50
 at java.util.ArrayList.subListRangeCheck(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ArrayList.subList(Unknown Source)
 at project1.Input.main(Input.java:30)

Comment: @GauravK Check splitAndReturn(nodes, 10).size(), if the list is < than 50 then the list you have given cant be splitted into 50 list of size 10. ie the  nodes.size will be less than 500.

Comment: It is giving me nodes.size as 1 no matter how many nodes I give as input.

Comment: @GauravK. Tested and optimized the code will work for sure..!! Check the new edit.

Comment: It was working perfectly fine. Instead of while (i + size < numbers.size()) I had written while (i + size > numbers.size()). Sorry for the mess up and thank you very much for help.

Comment: (i + size > numbers.size()) will be false at the first so it will terminate without getting in, so there will only be one splitting and it returns a list with size 1. Hope the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Well the simple thing to do is to loop through the list and split them accordingly. 
Considering your example,

> small = 100, med = 50, large = 10

first check if the list has enough values

```
if (list.size() >= ((small*10)+(med*30)+(large*50))){
    for (int i=0;i<small;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
            //copy array value
        }
    }    
    // do the same for med and large.
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I did not understand what do you mean by copy array value?

Comment: create the list for the current `small` outside the inner loop (say `smallList`) and assign `smallList.add(list.get(j))`

Comment: You could also loop through the list and use `subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)` to copy the value to a sublist.